# Notepad++ NppExec run in cmd

Tags: cmd, console, notepad++, nppexec

How can I make my commands run in NppExec run in cmd, as opposed to the built in console, which doesn't work with things like: "Press any key to continue", which only works when you press enter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to take a look at cmd /? output and http://ss64.com/nt/.  Using `start` along with `cmd /c` will give an external window and using `cmd /k` will keep it in the nppexec console.  One thing I don't like about the `/k` option is that it really isn't true as 'any key' doesn't do the trick and Enter needs to be used.

Test it out with `cmd /k pause` and `start cmd /c pause`.

Notice the `start` option has the window close, so any history will go away too.  If that's important then substitute `/k` for the `/c` and use `exit` when done.